# Как заставить Java выдавать полное значение числа?

Tags: java

Заместо 5.9049002E14 должно быть число 59049000000000.
Как принудительно заставить Java не коверкать числа?

Comment: Что значит не коверкать? Выводить в форме с фиксированной запятой, уменьшать на 2000000, что-то ещё?

Comment: @hitman249, число не исковеркано. Именно так оно и хранится в памяти.

Comment: попробуйте использовать тип BigDecimal.

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можно вот так

```
    NumberFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#"); 
    System.out.println(df.format(5.9049002E14));
```

будет 590490020000000

Answer (score 0):

файлик:

Main.java:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println(59049000000000L);
    }
}

$ javac Main.java ; java -cp . Main
59049000000000
```

что я делаю не так ? :)

Comment: @shurik, у Вас long, а у @hitman249 видимо double.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант, можно использовать `BigInteger`.